# Apollo React @client directive not returning cache value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo

I'm trying to use Apollo React client (under `apollo-boost 0.4.7`) for client-side state management.

I can fetch messages from my GraphQL server just fine, but a problem arises when I try to read/write to the local cache (that is, no server interaction whatsoever). I've read that I need to use the @client directive for my queries to [hit the cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/):

```
// index.js - The entry point of my webpacked app

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

import App from './app.jsx';  // My app component

// Initialize the cache
const cache =  new InMemoryCache();
cache.writeData({
    data: {
        testString: '',
    },
});

console.log(cache);  // Let's see what the cache holds

// Build the client
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: '/graphql',
    cache,
    resolvers: {
        testString: (root, params, { cache }) => {
            return 'Heyyyyyyy';
        },
    },
});


// Render the app exported by app.jsx
ReactDOM.render(<ApolloProvider client={client}><App /></ApolloProvider>, document.getElementById('test-app'));
```

I can see that the `testString` field is initialized in my ROOT_QUERY:

[image]

However, when I attempt to query on this `testString` field, the result is undefined:

```
// app.jsx - Inside the component

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(gql`{ testString @client }`);

console.log(error);  // undefined
console.log(data);  // undefined
```

**What is going on?**

Comment: data will still be undefined initially, even when fetching from cache

Comment: @DanielRearden Do you mean when `loading` is truthy? Even after the query finishes loading, the data is still undefined.